# Star Schema vs Snowflake Schema performance

Tags: performance, database-design

I'm begin to developing a scial sharing website so I'm curious about database design Schema... So in Data-Mining Star-Schema is the best one but how about a social sharing website... And as a nature of the SS websites there will be (i hope :)) many users in same time... Which better for performance for overdose using...

Comment: what? what's the question?  you seem to be confusing OLTP with OLAP...

Comment: Let's take a simplfy the situation... We're developing a social sharing site... Star Schema is the best for that site or Snow Flake Schema?... That's the main situation...

Answer (score 2):

What do you want to do? Star Schema and Snow Flake are reporting schemas. Social sharing would not need that except mayby then for **reporting**?

You need something representing the social relations, that is usually done with a graph database http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_database or in a RDBMS there are graph techniques such as [this](http://techportal.inviqa.com/2009/09/07/graphs-in-the-database-sql-meets-social-networks/) More details in the [book by Celko](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558609202)

Comment: so reporting will be needed sooner or later... Beside that your links are very useful thanks... At conclusion can we say Star Schema or Snow Flake not the best designs for social network?

Comment: What you can do is to define ER or Graph design database for your website, and when it will be time for reporting, you'll define a star schema design for a database that will be fed by the data coming from your first database. As oluies said Star/Snowflake schemas have a BI/Reporting goals not a web site database design.

Answer (score 0):

Star and Snowflake are not actually design methods. They are common patterns that arise as part or whole of a schema. As far as I'm aware the term "Snowflake" was invented by Ralph Kimball and is only relevant if you are using his "Dimensional" design methodology (which I certainly wouldn't recommend for a social networking site!).

The best default design for your database should generally be a Normal Form one. Aim to be in at least Boyce-Codd / 5th Normal Form unless you find compelling reasons to modify that.